# Why is the additive identity different to the multiplicative and exponential?

Tags: number-theory

The additive identity is 0.

The multiplicative and exponential identities are 1.

Exponentiation is repeated multiplication, and multiplication is repeated addition.

If you go up a further level, to repeated exponentiation, the identity is again 1.

If you use Knuth's Up-Arrow Notation, and the principles behind it, it's simple to see that 1 is an identity for all higher operations.

Why is addition the only operation with a different identity?

Comment: Let a,e be in R where e fulfills a+e=a for all a, then e must be 0... But you probably know that.

Comment: Exponentiation (and higher operations) has no two-sided identity.

Comment: There is no exponential identity. You shouldn't think of exponentiation as the sort of thing that has an identity; in particular, it's not associative.